# Python CSV reading. Sort by 2 columns using ascending and descending order

Tags: python, pandas, csv

csv file (https://www.kaggle.com/blitzr/movehub-city-rankings ->> movehubqualityoflife.csv)

I need to return the first five records, in order by the cities with the highest movehub ratings and the worst health care ratings

pls help me, friend.

Heres a look at my current code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("movehubqualityoflife.csv", delimiter=',')

df.sort_values(by='Movehub Rating', ascending=False)


df1 = pd.read_csv("movehubqualityoflife.csv", delimiter=',')

df1.sort_values(by='Health Care', ascending=True)
```

Comment: What is the expected behaviour, what is actually happening. Where is the actual question and problem?

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to do this by sorting 2 times the same dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("movehubqualityoflife.csv", delimiter=',')

df.sort_values(by='Movehub Rating', ascending=False)
df.sort_values(by='Health Care', ascending=True)
```

in that way, your dataframe will be sorted first by 'health care ascending' and secondly by 'movehub rating descending'.
Sort operations in dataframe objects are permanent.

Answer (score 0):

In order to save the new order you have set, you need to use inplace, so your changes will make permanent. An you can use head(5) to get the first 5

```
df.sort_values(by='Movehub Rating', ascending=False, inplace=True)

df1=df.head(5)
```

And then you can do it again for the 'Health Care'.
If you want to sort both of them (first by 'Movehub Rating', and after that by 'Health Care') you can do:

```
df.sort_values(by=['Movehub Rating','Health Care'], ascending=[False,True], inplace=True)

df1=df.head(5)
```